# A difficult functional equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Is it possible to solve the following functional equation-

Determine all functions $f: \mathcal{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ such that $f(f(x)-f(y))=f(f(x))-2x^2f(y)+f(y^2)$ for all reals $x,y$

Here , $\mathcal{R}$ denotes the set of all reals.

Comment: One thing that's interesting is that if $f$ has at least one non-zero root, then it has infinitely non-zero roots. If $a \neq 0$ and $f(a) = 0$, then $f(f(a)-f(a)) = f(f(a))-2a^2f(a)+f(a^2) \implies f(0-0) = f(0)-2a^2(0)+f(a^2) \implies f(0)= f(0)+f(a^2) \implies f(a^2) = 0$, i.e., $a^2$ is also a root of $f$ (as is $a^4, a^8,$ etc).

Comment: But what if a=1 or a=-1 ?

Comment: Good point, those had slipped my mind.

Comment: Letting $x=0$ and $y=0$, I think you can show that $f(f(0)) = 0$. Using that fact, if you let $x=0$, you end up with $f(f(0)-f(y)) = f(y^2)$. If $f$ was injective, then $f(0)-f(y) = y^2$ or $f(y) = f(0)-y^2$, a contradiction since $f(y) = f(0)-y^2$ is not injective and $f$ is injective. So whatever $f$ is, we know that it isn't injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that $f$ is not $0$.

1) I put first $a=f(0)$. Then $x=y=0$ gives $f(a)=0$. Putting $y=a$ gives $f(a^2)=0$, and replacing $x$ by $a$ gives $$f(-f(y))=a-2a^2f(y)+f(y^2)$$

2) Let $b$ such that $f(b)=0$. Replacing $x$ by $b$ gives 
$$f(-f(y))=a-2b^2f(y)+f(y^2)$$. By the above, this is true $b=a^2$. If $a^4\not =a^2$, then the two relations gives $f=0$. Hence we must have $a=0$ or $a=\pm 1$.

3) I suppose now that $a=f(0)=0$. We have hence $$f(-f(y))=f(y^2)\quad (1)$$ In addition, if $f(b)=0$, we must have $b=0$. If we put $x=y$, we get
$$f(f(x)=2x^2f(x)-f(x^2)\quad (2)$$

a) Let $x,y$ not zero, and suppose that $f(x)=f(y)$. Then we get that $f(x^2)=f(-f(x))=f(-f(y))=f(y^2)$, and $f(f(x))=f(f(y))$. Hence by (2), we have $f(x)(y^2-x^2)=0$. As $f(x)\not =0$, we find $y=\pm x$.

b) From (1), we get that $f(y)=\pm y^2$ for all $y$.

Suppose that $f(x)=-x^2$ By using (2), we get that $f(x^2)+f(-x^2)=-2x^4$. But as $f(\pm x^2)=\pm x^4$, we get that $f(x^2)=f(-x^2)=-x^4$.

Now if $f(y)=y^2$, by using (2) again, we show that $f(y^2)=y^4$.

c) Now suppose that there exists $x,y$, not zero, with $f(x)=-x^2$ and $f(y)=+y^2$. The original equation show that 
$$f(-x^2-y^2)=-x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4$$

But we must have $f(-x^2-y^2)=\pm (x^2+y^2)^2$, and it is easy to see that this is not the case.

d) Hence we must have $f(x)=-x²$ for all $x\not =0$, (hence for all $x$) or $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x$. It is easy to see that they both are solutions.

4) Now if $a=f(0)=\pm 1$, I think that we can follow the same way, If $f(0)=1$, then $f(1)=0$, if $f(b)=0$, then $b=\pm 1$ in the same way, etc.

I must say that I have not completed the computations. If I am not wrong, this leads to two other solutions, namely $f(x)=1-x^2$ and $f(x)=-1+x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the complete solution set but $$f(x)=x^2$$ certainly is a solution!

Comment: I tried assuming that $f(x) = x^2+g(x)$ for some function $g(x)$, hoping that I could show that $g(x) = 0$. Substituting this function of $f(x)$ into the equation and letting $x=y$ I got $g(0) = g(x)^2+g(x^2+g(x))+g(x^2)$ but this doesn't seem too useful.

Comment: Also, $f(x) = 0$ is also certainly a solution!

Comment: It is highly probable that the aforementioned two solutions are the only solutions but it is very difficult to prove  that :(